# on runtime paint the whole panels in the gui

Tags: swing

I want to be able to change the background color of the gui form.
If I change the parent panel gui - i want all of its descenders to get the same color.
Is it possible to do it without iterating on all comonents?
10x.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  When you say "descenders" do you mean child components?  Do you want to change the colors of all the components in your application or just some subset of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want components within your parent container to have the same background color you might setOpacity to false for them (at least for JPanels and other containers).

If you want your complete application to look differently you might consider switching to another Look&Feel (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).